# create a vector containing row IDs of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dataset, row

I am using one of Rs built in datasets called USArrests. It looks like instead of the rows having a numeric ID, they have a State as the row ID. Now how do I create a vector containing all of these state names?

I would generally use `myvec <- c(USArrests$colname)` but I am not sure how to access  the states as it is not considered a normal column

Comment: `myvec <- rownames(USArrests)`

Comment: That is not bult into RStudio. It is built into R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data("USArrests")
head(USArrests)

vector_of_names <- rownames(USArrests)

##if you want to append to the dataframe
USArrests$state_name <-rownames(USArrests)

USArrests
```

Comment: Or `USArrests %>% rownames_to_column()` if using the `tidyverse`.

Comment: Cheers guys, very helpful comments

Comment: I will of course, when the time limit allows me to. Thanks again for the help